# How do I force-skip Unsafe Working Conditions?

Tags: fallout-3

I'm playing Fallout 3 and I'm at the part of Unsafe Working Conditions where you have to listen to Ashur's speech, but he's not talking and it won't let me pass, and I have no clue how to help, do you know something?

Answer (score 4):

Got the following info from the Fallout 3 wiki:

> During Ashur's address in the square the speech can glitch causing him to stop half way, making it impossible to compete in The Hole or to progress the storyline. [verified]
>
> **Solution** (for consoles and PC): The only way to continue is to load an older save from before the speech and attend it again.
>
> **Solution 2** (only for PC): type "setstage xx00108b 120" in the console, where the "xx" is your load order for The Pitt (as it is in FOMM or the launcher). This will go to the next objective, skipping Ashur's speech. NOTE: there will be an invisible wall that you cannot pass, you will have to turn clipping off (type "tcl" in console)."

I love Fallout 3, shame about the many bugs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're playing on the PC, installing [The Pitt Reforged](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/16693/?) fix mod (included in the [Updated Unofficial Fallout 3 Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/19122/?)) will help prevent this issue from occurring.

Related fixes:

> - Moved several script triggers during Ashur's downtown speech so that he says the entire speech, and that he and Midea don't talk over each other.
> - For the duration of Ashur's downtown speech, locks the player's movement controls and moves the player near Midea for the duration of Ashur's speech. This avoids numerous bugs and crashes that can occur if the player interacts with certain characters or walks underneath the walkway during the speech.

If you can't install the mod, avoid interacting with other characters and walking underneath the walkway shortly before, and during Ashur's speech, to avoid triggering the bug.